# "Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin" in Maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I want to build a project in Maven using `eclipse-plugin` packaging, but I get the following error for my POM:

```
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin @ line 15, column 13 .
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent> 
    <relativePath>../releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <groupId>net.sf.logsaw</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent> 

  <artifactId>net.sf.logsaw.core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging> 

  <name>LogSaw Core Plugin</name> 
</project>
```

Comment: please share the code...

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <relativePath>../releng/pom.xml</relativePath>
  <groupId>net.sf.logsaw</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 <artifactId>net.sf.logsaw.core</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
 <name>LogSaw Core Plugin</name>
</project>

Comment: @ritesh: This comment was not helpful. All relevant information is present in the original question.

Answer (score 26):

The packaging type `eclipse-plugin` is defined by a Maven build extension called [Tycho](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.tycho). In order to use Tycho's packaging types, you need to configure Tycho as a build extension:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also, Tycho requires additional metadata files to be present, e.g. an OSGi manifest for `eclipse-plugin` modules. Another major difference of a Tycho project compared to a regular Maven project is that you have to configure the so-called [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform), e.g. by defining a repository with `layout=p2`, in case your project references any external artifacts. To get started, you may have a look at [this example project](http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho-demo.git/tree/itp01).

For more information, you can also check out [Tycho's documentation wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Category%3aTycho), e.g. the [reference card page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card).

Comment: Now I get the following error:
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve target platform specification artifact net.sf.logsaw:parent:target:workspace:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
and here is part of my pom :
<plugin>
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
<version>${tycho-version}</version>
<configuration>
<target>
<artifact>
<groupId>net.sf.logsaw</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<classifier>workspace</classifier>
</artifact>
</target>

Comment: and when i comment the target element i get this error : Missing requirement: net.sf.logsaw.core 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 0.0.0' but it could not be found. Any idea plz ?

Comment: @ritesh The sonatype blog you linked is outdated in many aspects. E.g. `-Dtcho.targetPlatform` is deprecated.

Comment: @dev Follow-up questions are discouraged on stackoverflow. Check if your question is already answered elsewhere, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I find a project folder has pom.xml with `<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>` , the project cannot import to eclipse,

after go to upper root level folder, the root folder pom.xml has `<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>`, this root folder can import to eclipse, all child projects shows successfully.