# Convert java plugin into maven project with eclipse-plugin packaging

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, maven-eclipse-plugin

I am quite experienced with java but i'm using maven for the first time.
i have installed Eclipse Kepler (Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers), I have installed Tychus as well with the "add new software" button.

There is an [Internet of things project](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/.m2e/connectors/m2eclipse-tycho/0.8.0/N/LATEST/) that I cloned and built called OM2M.
I followed the install wiki step by step and everything work until then.
[cloning wiki here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Clone)

I want to develop my own OSGI module so I went to the 'developer' section of the wiki and once again and created a new plugin project.
When i try to convert this plugin project into a maven project ( [link to the step i'm talking about](https://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/Developer#Convert_the_plugin_into_maven_project) ) I don't have to "eclipse-plugin" packaging type for my pom [wiki screenshot here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/File:Maven_conversionbis.png).

I looked it up on the web and apparently it has something to do with Tychus that needs configuration, I tried typing it in the box but obviously I have problems when i try to build, I tried editing the main pom.xml with stuff I found but none of them work and I really don't know what to do to make it work.

Do you guys have an idea ?
Thanks

Edit : i forgot to mention that i read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639162/unknown-packaging-eclipse-plugin-in-maven) but I don't understand the the answers, I don't know where to put the code the top answer is talking about nor do i know where to but the OSGI manifest.

Edit 2 : pom.xml i get when i enter eclipse-plugin by hands : 
If i write eclipse-plugin by hand here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.om2m</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipu</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
</project>
```

Edit 3 : I managed to remove the error by setting the main pom.xml as a parent but now when i try to build i have the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-packaging-plugin:0.20.0:validate-version (default-validate-version) on project org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipu: Unqualified OSGi version 1.0.0.qualifier must match unqualified Maven version 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT for SNAPSHOT builds ->
```

I've searched for the goals but I don't know where to set or edit them.

Edit 4 : Thanks to @Wim Anckaert i've dropped the .qualifier and the .snapshot from the pom.xml and the manifest and now it seems to be working !
Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last error seems to be a problem with the <**version**> of your ./pom.xml and **Bundle-Version** of your ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. These should be equal to each other.

A part of our pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>be.cs.fashion.awg.core</artifactId>
<name>CERPS</name>
<version>2.1.0</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
```

A part of our MANIFEST.MF

```
Bundle-Name: CERPS
Bundle-SymbolicName: be.cs.fashion.awg.core;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 2.1.0
Bundle-Localization: plugin
```

So in your case version in pom.xml version should be "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" or you should use Bundle-Version "0.0.1.qualifier"
We dropped the "-SNAPSHOT" and the ".qualifier" in our versions.

Answer (score 0):

The value "eclipse-plugin" is not included in the combo (i.e. the drop-down listbox [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/File:Maven_conversionbis.png)), you ought to write it by hand.

**Upd:** Firstly you must enable tycho. To do this, add

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.24.0</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

to your `pox.xml` (or, preferably, to its parent).

Then, you need to know that the wizard you show on screenshot **does not** *search* for all possible values of  tag, instead it adds to "Packaging" drop-down listbox most usable values and allows you to enter any value that you want.

For more details check out [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card)

Comment: @trincot : I've updated my post with the pom.xml i get when i write it by hand.
I've got an error here :  "  <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>" saying "build error : unknown packaging type"

Comment: Just for avoiding misunderstanding, I am not the one who answered. I just improved the phrasing of the answer. You want to talk to @rusnavu.

Comment: Oh right sorry :) I'm kinda new.
@rusnavu I've updated my post with the pom.xml i get when i write it by hand. I've got an error here : " <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>" saying "build error : unknown packaging type"
See my edits for more information.

Comment: @Sherokan Sorry for the long silence. I've update my answer.