# POM maven Parent issue HOW to

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

this is my first Maven plugin project and I am following this guide 
http://wiki.eclipse.org/OM2M/one/Developer

yet , I am having similar issue with this thread
[Convert java plugin into maven project with eclipse-plugin packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789200/convert-java-plugin-into-maven-project-with-eclipse-plugin-packaging)

he said "Edit 3 : I managed to remove the error by setting the main pom.xml as a parent but now when i try to build i have the following error :", I do want to know how he did that

here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipe</groupId>
 <artifactId>org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipe</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

</project>
```

build properties

```
source.. = src/main/java
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
```

Location:

```
C:\Users\Ahmad\workspace\org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipe
           .
```

Path:
      /org.eclipse.om2m.sample.ipe

the error is on POM 
     eclipse-plugin

it says Unknown packaging

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639162/unknown-packaging-eclipse-plugin-in-maven). The most voted answer states that:

> The packaging type eclipse-plugin is defined by a Maven build extension called Tycho.
>
> In order to use Tycho's packaging types, you need to configure Tycho as a build extension:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You might also want to take a look at [this post](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1072262/) in the Eclipse Community Forum.
The user [Francois Assoui](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=usrinfo&id=205233&) states that:

> The "eclipse-plugin" packaging is not available in the standard set of
>   maven packaging. It is provided by the Maven plugin Tycho made for
>   handling OSGi plugins compilation and creation of sites (project that
>   gather a set of plugins for a specific configuration).
>
> At the state where you have to enter the packaging, the IDE can not
>   give you the right choice as it does not know that we are going to use
>   Tycho. You have to type it manually and you will have an error at that
>   time. But you just have to make the link to the parent project in the
>   next step to solve this error. In fact, the parent project imports the
>   Tycho plugin.

Comment: thanks Marc, however where that "build extension" is?

Comment: Note that the provided code contains both `<build>` and `<extensions>` tags, so that's how you tell Maven to use build extension(s). For more detailed information, please refer to [this topic](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Extensions) in the documentation.