# Unable to resolve "eclipse-plugin" packaging type with Tycho 1.0.0 in pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho

I'm trying to build an Eclipse plugin. I'm using Tycho 1.0.0 to package the jar with `<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>`. Maven is giving me the error "Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin". When searching that I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17639162/unknown-packaging-eclipse-plugin-in-maven) that didn't help.

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>My_Plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>My_Plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<properties>
    <TYCHO.VERSION>1.0.0</TYCHO.VERSION>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${TYCHO.VERSION}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Here is my `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: My Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: My_Plugin;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.myplugin.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: MYPLUGIN
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui.editors,
 org.eclipse.ui.ide,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor,
 org.eclipse.jface.text
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.myplugin.mypackages
```

Comment: Remove the <pluginManagement> tags. (https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build `<extensions>` must be declared below `project/build/plugins`, not below `project/build/pluginManagement/plugins` (or, if you like, below [`project/build/extensions`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Extensions)). Thus, the following fixes the issue and registers the `eclipse-plugin` packaging:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${TYCHO.VERSION}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```